# List (of T) search vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, list

How can I search my list?
I want to validate the barcode when I add it.

```
Public Class item2
 Private m_name As String
 Private m_barcode As Integer
 Private m_Price As Double
 Private m_Quinety As Integer
 Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_name = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Barcode() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_barcode
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_barcode = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Price() As Double
    Get
        Return m_Price
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        m_Price = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Quinety() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Quinety
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_Quinety = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim ItemsList As New List(Of item2)()
End class
```

I have been searching the internet found something like this:

```
dim zz as item2 = ItemsList.Find(Function(p) p.Barcode = 12345689)
```

But it does not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Try to be a little more specific than "it does not work".

Comment: What is `Function(p) p.Barcode = 12345689` supposed to be doing?

Comment: You cannot access private members they need to be `Friend` or `Public`. Plus it is called `m_barcode`.

Comment: You should create a `property` for this.

Comment: @J0e3gan what i mean is that at zz is always null even tho the barcode(12345689) is in the list

Comment: @TonyHinkle it take the object with the barcode and put it in zz

Comment: @OneFineDay i changed to public and m_barcode still the same

Comment: As indicated in the comment on my answer, you have not posted **all relevant code** here. Please add the additional code for the `Barcode` property. Until done so we cannot troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Why is `ItemsList` declared in the class of `item2`?

Comment: And what do you mean `it does not work`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to build and run your code, it does not seem like trying to access a private member (i.e. `m_barcode` vs. a public `Barcode` member) is the problem.

It seems then that the `item2` class you have shown in your question is incomplete.  Adding a public `Barcode` property to it to get/set the private `m_barcode` field, though, here is a simple example that works as it sounds like you want:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ItemsList As New List(Of item2)()
        Dim foo As New item2()
        Dim bar As New item2()

        foo.Barcode = 12345689
        ItemsList.Add(foo)

        bar.Barcode = 98654321
        ItemsList.Add(bar)

        Dim zz As item2 = ItemsList.Find(Function(p) p.Barcode = 12345689)

        Debug.WriteLine(zz.Barcode.ToString()) ' outputs 12345689
    End Sub

    Public Class item2
        Private m_name As String
        Private m_barcode As Integer
        Private m_Price As Double
        Private m_Quinety As Integer

        Public Property Barcode() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_barcode
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                m_barcode = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Module
```

Note that you should reconsider your naming and casing conventions, as `item2` is a strange class name.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not doing any data validation in your `Set`s, I would suggest auto properties.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ItemsList As New List(Of Item2)
    ItemsList.Add(New Item2 With {.Name = "Toy Truck", .Barcode = 12345689, .Price = "10.00", .Quinety = 100})
    ItemsList.Add(New Item2 With {.Name = "Bicycle", .Barcode = 98754152, .Price = "100.00", .Quinety = 50})

    Dim foundItem = ItemsList.Find(Function(i) i.Barcode = 12345689)
    If Not foundItem Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(foundItem.Name)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Item not found")
    End If

    foundItem = ItemsList.Find(Function(i) i.Barcode = 1111)
    If Not foundItem Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(foundItem.Name)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Item not found")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Class Item2
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Barcode As Integer
    Public Property Price As Double
    Public Property Quinety As Integer
End Class
```

Results:

[image]